# Line wrapping within emacs *compilation* buffer

Tags: emacs, compilation, buffer, word-wrap

I have a little problem with compiling my project in emacs. The *compilation* buffer does not line-wrap and I have some very long compile and link commands which I would like to sanity check sometimes.

Does anyone know how to force line-wrap on the output added to the *compilation* buffer, ideally as it is added (a la auto-fill).

VBR, Mark.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun my-compilation-mode-hook ()
  (setq truncate-lines nil) ;; automatically becomes buffer local
  (set (make-local-variable 'truncate-partial-width-windows) nil))
(add-hook 'compilation-mode-hook 'my-compilation-mode-hook)
```

Comment: That nearly works, but after the first compilation, all my other buffers have this auto-wrap. Do you know how to limit the auto-wrap to only the compilation buffer?

Comment: Works like a charm. Except 2 closing parens too much at the end.

Comment: @Gauthier: with my recent edit, the effect should be limited to the compilation buffer.